# how to use cacti to monitor remote hosts

Tags: nagios, cacti

I have nagios installed in a server and it's monitoring different remote hosts using different plugins. But I am not able to view the process of each system in a graph format. Is it possible to use cacti for the same purpose? I just installed cacti on the same machine. But not sure how to install plugins and monitor different servers. Also just wanted to know can I use cacti as the frontend tool for Nagios? How cacti works

Can someone help me on this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on how Cacti interacts with Nagios, but I do have the pnp4nagios plugin/extension installed and configured for one of my Nagios Instances which gives me a great overview in graphs for the services I monitor. (not all of them, but only those who are variable and are usefull to see in a graph) It's a really nice tool and not so hard to setup. I compiled it from source and it's install.php gives you great feedback on what to do next in the installation procedure. One thing they didn't mention was that you had to enable Includes in your Nagios instance's apache2 config file. (this is necessary if you want to use the SSI include in the Nagios CGI files. This SSI file contains jQuery Javascript definitions that will enable the popUp png graphs when you mouseover a graph in Nagios)
It also uses rrdtool (Round Robin Database files) which uses fixed size storage.
(could be beneficial if you have little space on your harddrive)

Answer (score 0):

For nagios there is nagiosgraph, it generates graph for each services define in nagios, you just have to add config for nagiosgraph.

as for cacti, there is plugin called NPC, it is generate new tab on cacti which contains services define in nagios.